# removing multiple tags in SGML

Tags: c#, sgml

i have a sgml file like

```
<p><p><data>sdlksdskdmskdmsamdakmdksam<p></data>...
```

my question is how to remove one tag `<p>` and keep another one intact ...which regular expression would be siutable......

Comment: is the third <p> meant to be a </p>?

Comment: i want to remove first<p> tag and keep other 2 intact

Comment: removing only the first appearing <p>not the second and last one

Comment: This has been asked zillion times now! Seems to be a university assignment :)

Comment: <P><P>JUDGMENT<P> stion for the opinion of this court:<P> "Whether, on the facts and circumstances of the case, the Tribunal is justified in remanding the case when the Commissioner of Income-tax (Appeals) has deleted the addition made on the basis of the report of estimate of stock found by the inspector ?"<P> The application is allowed partly.<P> on extraction i want only the first <P> and last <P> to be removed so all other<p>'s appearing inside the judgement body should be intact

Answer (score 1):

If your SGML is such it can be processed as XML, then [XProc](http://www.w3.org/TR/xproc/) is a good technology for this kind of thing, with a single step such as:

```
<p:unwrap match="p[parent::p]"/>
```

(Assuming you want to remove all self-nested p elements until p never wraps itself).

You definitely do **not** want to process SGML/XML with regexps unless you are 100% certain you will be dealing with a subset which has a certain well-specified lexical form. Think for example how you'd process stuff with comments using a regexp:

```
<p><!-- <p> commented out--><foo><p/><p/></foo></p>
```

!!